# Insert a list of links to the related products image area in commerce kickstart 2 drupal

Tags: commerce

How to insert a list of links to the related products image area (leading into a specific place in the product display of that product) in commerce kickstart 2 drupal

E.g. In the product display page where it shows the product images and the details like Title, SKU, Price, Quantity and add to cart image, I have added a jquery tab field under it which includes 3 tabs (Description1, Description2, Description3).

Under that field, I have added a block with the related products (products that belong in the same category). It shows the title of the product and the image.

Under the image I want to place a link for each of the above tabs (Description1, Description2, Description3) which when is clicked it will lead me to the page of the specific product and at the place int it where I can see the beginning of the tab.

For example:
When I click in the link description 2 of the product 3 (related product) it should get me to the products 3 product display page and move have the page scrolled down to the position where the tabs of product 3 appear.

Comment: You could improve your question by clarifying exactly what libraries you're using to make the "tabs" and what research you've done to try and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say from your question, but I think what you want is deep linking (clicking a link takes you to a particular tabbed description). If that is the case, then you might need some custom jquery that uses the Drupal core included [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) library to modify the url when the tabs are clicked, then modify your tabbing library to interpret parameters in the urls as which tabs you want to be viewed. I'd imagine if your library doesn't support it, it will all require some javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you are proposing seems logical. I thought that drupal could deal with this issue. I am going to try to follow your solution to my problem and come back to you with the result. Thank you again!